# Farpoint Spread control captures Ctrl+Z instead fo MenuItem

Tags: c#, winforms, menuitem, spread, farpoint

I have a form where there is shortcut applied to a MenuItem. The problem is that when the focus is inside the Spread control it traps the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> press and the shortcut never fires. 
If the focus is placed on a different control (ex. TextBox) the shortcut fires the `MenuItem_Click` event without a problem.

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 0):

[Farpoint Spread support](http://www.clubfarpoint.com/farpointsupportsite/modules/docs/spreadwin5help/spwin-undoredo.html) states:

> The input maps include new items to **map the CTRL+Z** and CTRL+Y keys to
>   the new UndoAction and RedoAction action objects, respectively. These
>   actions make calls into the UndoManager to the Undo and Redo methods,
>   respectively.

Can you use a different key combination?

Comment: No. Different key combination is not an option as this needs to invoke an undo on the entire form, not just the Spread control. Is there an option to get certain external method to be called maybe when keys are pressed?